# The return function I wrote in the container is not activated

Tags: android-studio, flutter

[enter image description here][1]

Hello, first of all, I have been dealing with a bug since yesterday and I could not find the problem, but it does not work.
It needs to go to _homepagestate but it doesn't
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeonQ.png

Comment: needs to go to _homepagestate ? Is it another screen you want to navigate to? To navigate to another screen you need to use the Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to navigate to the other page of your app. Try the following code.

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => HomePage(),
    ),
  );
```